# how can I take the value of a NumericUpDown in C# and use it for something ex. use as an int

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm making a Higher Lower game, and the number of tries the user has to guess the computer's number, I want to set using a NumbericUpDown.

How can I do this?

(Should  I paste my code here so you can see what I have so far?)

Comment: Sure. It's usually a good idea to paste at least a little code.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `Value` property of the control?  See the examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx).

For example,

```
this.upDown.Value = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks! but what if I want the user to pick a number.  Ex. "this.upDown.Value = int x;"  ?

Comment: Can you explain your issue a little more?

Comment: Sure.  I'm trying to make a higher-lower game (the computer generates a random number between 1 and 10.  Your job is to guess the number.  After each guess the computer tells you if its number is higher, or lower than the number you guessed.)

I'm trying to add difficulty by using lives (or tries).  I want the user to be able to pick how many lives they think it'll take them to guess the computer's number.

To do this, I created another form, and put in a "numericUpDown".

Once they choose their number, I want that number to be their lives.  How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't the user just click the up/down control to change the number of guesses?  In that case, you'll just read the Value property of the control.

Comment: if (wrong == true)
            {
                label3.Text = (int.Parse(label3.Text) - 1).ToString();
                if (label3.Text == "0")
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("You have lost! The randomized number was " + randomNumber + ". Would you like to play again ?", "You lost!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        randomNumber = number.Next(1, 10);
                        label3.Text = "3";
                        textBox1.Clear();
                    }
                    else
                    {

Comment: this.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (guessedNumber > randomNumber)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Your too high, go lower!", "Your Wrong!");
                        textBox1.Clear();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Higher!", "Wrong!");
                        textBox1.Clear();

Comment: Paste the code in the question, and then I'll see what I can make of it.